# In sqlite3, is reset required after a failed call to step?

Tags: c, sqlite

Is it a requirement to call `sqlite3_reset()` on a prepared statement after a failed call to `sqlite3_step()`? I'm using sqlite3 version 3.23.1. The lifecycle of my prepared statements is as follows:

1. At the start of my application, I globally do `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` and keep the handle to the prepared statement available for the lifetime of the application.
2. When I'm ready to do a query, I invoke one of the `sqlite3_bind_*()` functions, then do `sqlite3_step()` on that statement until I get something other than `SQLITE_ROW` returned.
3. Then the code below is executed to reset the statement.

Here is the part of the code that happens after I call `sqlite3_step()`. Note that variable `resultCode` holds the return value of the last call to `sqlite3_step()`.

```
   if (resultCode == SQLITE_DONE || resultCode == SQLITE_ROW)
   {
      if (sqlite3_reset(m_statement) != SQLITE_OK)
      {
         LogDbFailure(*m_db, "sqlite3_reset()");
      }
   }
   else
   {
      LogDbFailure(*m_db, "sqlite3_step()");
      success = false;
   }
```

Notice that if the call to step failed, I don't do a reset. Nothing in the documentation or search results on Google indicate that `sqlite3_reset()` must be called on failures. In fact, the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html) states that calling `sqlite3_reset()` after a failure will also fail:

> If the most recent call to sqlite3_step(S) for the prepared statement S indicated an error, then sqlite3_reset(S) returns an appropriate error code.

Reading this made me think that maybe I shouldn't call the reset function if step fails.

Can anyone clarify? Note in my case, `sqlite3_step()` is failing because of `SQLITE_BUSY`. I am using WAL journalling mode. Once step fails on a prepared statement, that prepared statement is forever in busy state when I call `sqlite3_step()`. Calls to `sqlite3_bind_*()` after that return `sqlite3_bind_int64() failed (21): bad parameter or other API misuse` (log format is my own, but 21 is  the error code), which makes me think that reset *should* be called in failure cases, since all errors seem to indicate that the database is busy because of the prepared statement stuck in mid-transaction due to the lack of a reset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Notice that if the call to step failed, I don't do a reset. Nothing in
>   the documentation or search results on Google indicate that
>   `sqlite3_reset()` must be called on failures.

Well no, not *specifically*, but [the docs for `sqlite3_reset()`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html) do say

> The sqlite3_reset() function is called to reset a prepared statement
>   object back to its initial state, ready to be re-executed.

You add,

> In fact, the documentation
>   states that calling `sqlite3_reset()` after a failure will also fail:
>
> > If the most recent call to sqlite3_step(S) for the prepared statement S indicated an error, then sqlite3_reset(S) returns an
> >     appropriate error code.

No, you are misinterpreting that.  There is an important distinction between "returns an appropriate error code" and "will fail".  That should be clearer when considered in the context of this excerpt from [the docs for `sqlite3_step()`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html):

> In the legacy interface, the sqlite3_step() API always returns a
>   generic error code, SQLITE_ERROR, following any error other than
>   SQLITE_BUSY and SQLITE_MISUSE. You must call sqlite3_reset() or
>   sqlite3_finalize() in order to find one of the specific error codes
>   that better describes the error.

Although that behavior of `sqlite3_step()` applies only to the legacy interface, not the V2 interface, it explains why the return value of `sqlite3_reset()` reports on the result of previous calls (if any) to `sqlite3_step()`, not on its own success or failure.  It is implicit that the reset itself cannot fail, or at least cannot report on its own failure via its return code.

> Reading this made me think that maybe I shouldn't call the reset
>   function if step fails.

The docs for `sqlite3_step()` have this to say on that point:

> For all versions of SQLite up to and including 3.6.23.1, a call to
>   sqlite3_reset() was required after sqlite3_step() returned anything
>   other than SQLITE_ROW before any subsequent invocation of
>   sqlite3_step().

Note: it is therefore *not wrong* to call `sqlite3_reset()` after `sqlite3_step()` reports an error.  The docs go on to say,

> Failure to reset the prepared statement using
>   sqlite3_reset() would result in an SQLITE_MISUSE return from
>   sqlite3_step(). But after version 3.6.23.1 (2010-03-26, sqlite3_step()
>   began calling sqlite3_reset() automatically in this circumstance
>   rather than returning SQLITE_MISUSE.

That seems inconsistent with the behavior you report, but note that,

> [...] The SQLITE_OMIT_AUTORESET
>   compile-time option can be used to restore the legacy behavior.

Thus, your safest bet is to reset the statement unconditionally, rather than to avoid resetting it after an error is reported.  That might be unnecessary with many SQLite3 builds, but it is not wrong or harmful, and it is necessary with some builds.

Comment: Thanks. I think some of these quotes apply to versions earlier than mine, but maybe there's a design flaw where somehow these rules still impact the later versions. I think your point, however, is to be generous with the reset regardless of the disclaimers to be safe.

Comment: @void.pointer, all of the documentation quotes are drawn from the current documentation as of today.  They apply to your version.  There are historic reasons for why the interface came to be the way it is, but that the design carries historical baggage does not mean you can expect it to behave differently than is documented.  And to the extent that the docs allow the possibility of varying behavior, yes, my point is that your code should accommodate *all* of the documented possibilities.

Comment: I know the current documentation applies to my version, but I'm talking about the backward compatibility notes. For example, it says that after 3.6.23.1, that reset is now called by step. As I designed my system, I omitted explicit calls in favor of this. Stuff like this is misleading, because I'm not seeing the behavior I expect based on the documentation & version I'm using. I'm likely misunderstanding the documentation, because honestly it's very confusing, but at the end of the day I'll just call reset and be done with it. There's too many edge cases.

Comment: @void.pointer, the docs say that since 3.6.23.1, the reset is called automatically by `sqlite3_step()`, ***except that*** the original behavior (not automatically resetting) can be selected by a compile-time option.  That would be an option of the SQLite compilation, not that of your program.  My point, then, is that unless you are in control of the SQLite build, or can verify this detail of it, the safest alternative is to not rely on the auto-reset.

Comment: Moreover, the SQLite docs couch the auto-reset as a fallback, its introduction justified by the fact that failing to reset constitutes a programming error.  In that sense, although resetting after an error may not be *required* by all SQLite builds, it is always expected and appropriate.